# Using dijit Controls on dojo.gfx surface

Tags: dojo, dijit.form, dojox.gfx

I'm successfully using dojo.gfx (surface) to draw an interactive part of my page. Now, I'd like to add some functionality, which is already provided in the form of dijit.form elements or some dojox controls (e.g. dojox.gauges).

The controls should be used for both input and output (buttons, sliders, checkboxes, gauges,...), so it seems to be a good idea to combine home-made graphics (dojo.gfx) with pre-built controls (dijit or dojox).

Is there an example on how to do this? One thing I'm aware of is that z-order could be an interesting issue (shapes drawn on a surface vs. dijit or dojox controls).

**Solution**

Just had some real problems getting things to work, but in the end the solution was obvious:

- created a <div> with fixed size (the same as the surface), otherwise scrolling would not work correctly
- added the controls to the parent of the <div&tg; where the surface is created
- Z-ordering is a bit of a problem as the whole surface is either in front or behind a control, so it is not possible to have parts of the drawing in front and other parts behind of a control

Comment: Please, provide en example of what have you tried and what are the issues you are having, or your question can be marked as `Low Quality`

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide an example, as I'm searching for an example or some ideas to start this. 
Even ans answer like "can't be done" would help...

Comment: add some more details.. this is not enough to answer... or simply you can add jsfiddle for whatever u have done and ask something to add after... that will be better...

Comment: I tried the following:

var c = new CheckBox({check: true,label: "check me"});
var r = this.surface.createRect({x: 10,y: 10,width: 100,height: 100,r: 1}).setStroke({color: "black", width: 1});
c.startup();
r.rawNode.appendChild(c.domNode);

The rectangle shows up, the checkbox doesn't.
Trying this in Chrome and using the developer tools to inspect the objects, I can see an <svg> with the contained <rect> and this contains a <div> representing the CheckBox object, but the Checkbox does not show up.
I'm quite sure, the <div> should not be a descendant of <svg>...